# How to change permissions of Wordpress and/or apache on macOS securely?

Tags: security, permissions

I have encountered a problem when trying to add an image to WordPress:

> "Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2017/05. Is its parent
>   directory writable by the server?"

.
Thing is that I installed WordPress locally, without `MAMP`. Root for `Apache` is `/Library/WebServer`, port is `80`.

Already tried adding `define( 'UPLOADS', 'wp-content/uploads' );` to `wp-config.php`, but it didn't work. According to this, I assume that problems are with permissions of WordPress to `/Library/WebServer`.

Anyone knows how to change this permissions securely?

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/83/how-to-to-secure-wordpress-file-and-folder-permissions